# Restful call returns Bad Request. Success in RestSharp. Failed with HttpClient/HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, api, rest, .net-core, restsharp

Alright! So I have this Restful call that i am trying to make to a Polycom device.

To sort of isolate within this code I used RestSharp and it works fine. Also removing the credentials object or altering it makes it kick back an unauthorized so i believe authorization is fine. I think its the body/parameters that are incorrect.

```
        //THIS SECTION WORKS 
        //RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
        //restRequest.AddJsonBody(body);
        //RestClient restClient = new RestClient(targetUrl);
        //restClient.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sPoint, cert, wRequest, certProb) => true;
        //restClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, deskPhone.MACPassword);
        //IRestResponse restsharpResponse = await restClient.ExecutePostAsync(restRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //END SECTION
```

What my issue is.. I have no idea why I am getting an error 400 Bad Request. When I look at what I have in the call it all seems to align correctly. The Auth token is the same as RestSharp and the body is the same object.

I really am at a loss for what i can do and unfortunately I cant use restsharp i need to use what is available in Net Core.

I have a few different implementations in the code as you can see below. I attempted with HttpClient and I attempted with HttpWebRequest.

My question is... What likely bug do i have that is preventing this from being a proper request.

This link here is to API documentation which I also seem to be aligning with correctly.
https://support.polycom.com/content/dam/polycom-support/products/voice/polycom-uc/other-documents/en/2018/ucsoftware-restapi.pdf

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public async Task PhoneNumberStuff(long userId)
    {
        DeskPhone deskPhone = DbContext.DeskPhones
            .Include(x=>x.DeskPhoneUser)                
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeskPhoneUserId == 11546);
        string targetUrl = $"https://{deskPhone.IPv4Address}/api/v1/callctrl/dial";
        string certLcation = @"C:\Users\AlexRoundy\Desktop\Polycom.cer";

        string username = "Polycom";
        SecureString password = new NetworkCredential("", deskPhone.MACPassword).SecurePassword;

        String encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + deskPhone.MACPassword));

        //$cred = New - Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
        NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        string body = @"{""data"":{""Dest"": ""7168675309"", ""Line"": ""1"",""Type"": ""TEL"" } }";


        //THIS SECTION WORKS 
        //RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest();
        //restRequest.AddJsonBody(body);
        //RestClient restClient = new RestClient(targetUrl);
        //restClient.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sPoint, cert, wRequest, certProb) => true;
        //restClient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, deskPhone.MACPassword);
        //IRestResponse restsharpResponse = await restClient.ExecutePostAsync(restRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //END SECTION 

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        //handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sPoint, cert, wRequest, certProb) => true;
        //handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
        handler.Credentials = credential;
        //handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUrl);

        request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sPoint, cert, wRequest, certProb) => true;
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
        request.Accept = "application/json";

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(body);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string responseText;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));




        StringContent temp = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");



        HttpRequestMessage httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, targetUrl);
        httpMessage.Content = temp;


        HttpResponseMessage testA = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);

        HttpResponseMessage stuff = await httpClient.PostAsync(targetUrl, temp).ConfigureAwait(false);

        handler.Dispose();
        httpMessage.Dispose();

        httpClient.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: First thing to do is compare them in fiddler.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not getting 400 response in restsharp code? How does you verify that?

Comment: The General! That actually is what i did right after posting this... im about to share.

Comment: Chetan I know that it wasnt a 400 response because in debugger i got back a 200 and also because the endpoint did its job and dialed me correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So below are the two comparisons from fiddler.

The problem child is this line here.

```
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

The fix??

```
request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

The following below is the fiddler results that led to the discovery.

POST https://192.168.50.76/api/v1/callctrl/dial HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic UG9seWNvbTp3TUh0bDNKdA==
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: RestSharp/106.11.4.0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 60
Host: 192.168.50.76

{"data":{"Dest": "7164171568", "Line": "1","Type": "TEL" } }

POST https://192.168.50.76/api/v1/callctrl/dial HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic UG9seWNvbTp3TUh0bDNKdA==
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
User-Agent: FauxPaux
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Content-Type: application/json;
Content-Length: 60
Host: 192.168.50.76

{"data":{"Dest": "7164171568", "Line": "1","Type": "TEL" } }